# Почему в first_item попадает последний элемент односвязного списка? Что там не так с "памятью из кучи"?

Tags: c, односвязный-список

Функция преобразует массив размером "size" в односвязный перечень. Чтобы сэкономить на системных вызовах, выделяю память из кучи одним разом. В результате в first_item **попадает последний элемент**.
В чем проблема?

```
struct item_of_list *array_to_list(const int *array, int size){

struct item_of_list *first_item=NULL,
*current_item = NULL,
*last_item=NULL;

current_item = malloc( sizeof(*first_item) * size );
/*Мне кажется, что проблема вот здесь и я не правильно понимаю, как память выделяется из кучи*/

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    /*Здесь я на каждой итерации создаю и заполняю следующий элемент списка*/
    current_item->data = *(array+i);
    current_item->next=NULL;

    if (last_item) {
        /*Добавляю заполненный элемент в список, если не пуст*/
        last_item->next=current_item;
        last_item = last_item->next;

    } else {
        /*Если список был пуст, то все указатели указывают на первый добавленный элемент списка*/
        first_item=last_item=current_item;
    }
}
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я переклав через перекладач. Надіюся, що всі тут видихнули з полегшенням.)

Comment: Вы всё время заполняете одно и то же место в начале выделенной области. И по большому счёту, то ,что вы делаете - просто массив, указатели на следующий элемент не нужны.

Comment: @MBo, Я зрозумів, дякую. Виходить, що я виділяю купу місця, а користую тільки її початок розміром зі структуру.

Comment: Да, так. Думаю, поможет делать current_item++ после его заполнения, чтобы на следующем цикле заполнялось новое место.

Comment: @MBo, в моменті, де "добавляв наступний елемент в непустий список" добавив `current_item++` вниз тіла `If` і все спрацювало. Дякую)
Тепер розумію, що для такої ф-ції це (виділення пам'яті одним шматком) немає сенсу, бо вона створює кожного разу новий список. Це було б доцільно для ф-ції, що редагує уже наявний. Іще раз дякую)

Comment: Я не всё понял - но да смысла в такой конструкции нет. В принципе, свой менеджер памяти, который сначала  получит большой непрерывный кусок, потом будет вам выдавать куски памяти, имеет  некоторый смысл, но штатный менеджер памяти трудно будет обогнать.

Comment: @MBo, (Пишу на русском как могу - не судите). Задумка была в том, чтобы при больших размерах масива (что подается в ф-цию) моя ф-ция не тратила лишнее время на многократные обращения к ОС за памятью из кучи. Если бы моя ф-ция принимала 3-им параметром конец списка и добавляла в него, а елементов масива было бы больше милиона - разница в скорости была бы ощутима, а одноразовый резерв "кучной" памяти был бы кстати.

Comment: Закрывайте вопрос, @MBo, дал ответ в коментарии. Спасибо, @MBo)

Answer (score 0):

А какой средой разработки пользуетесь?
VS, например, подчеркивает 2 ошибки в месте, где Вы выделяете память, например то, что выделяете память под указатель на тип, а не на тип как таковой, и то что malloc возвращает void*, а у Вас, item_of_list*.

Так же, насколько я понимаю, суть связных списков в том, что они не находятся в памяти подряд, как массив. А Вы пытаетесь разово выделить память под весь список. Думаю, экономия на системных вызовах тут неуместна

Comment: Користуюся Vim - 10/10)
Виділив пам'ять під "розіменований вказівник", що і є структурою. (чи я щось не так зрозумів?)